# How to align text in the article use tikz node to emphasize

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I hope to use tikz to make some emphasized content in the article,

I chose to use tikz to make this effect,

But the nodes of tikz are not very beautifully aligned.

Below is my code, how to make the text aligned,

My tikz is not well understood. Trying to use the yshift option has no effect.

Trying to use the \vspace{} command has no effect. What should I do?

I'm looking forward to the help of the master.

Below is my code：

```
 \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document} 
 \Huge 
  Here are some test text{ \tikz \draw (0,-1) node[draw,minimum width=1mm, minimum height=1mm, align=center,inner sep=0.5mm, outer sep=0mm,rectangle,fill = gray] {Some texts to emphasize}; }
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `\tikz[baseline=A.base]` where `A` is the name of the node.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `soul`?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\sethlcolor{lightgray}
\begin{document} 
{\Huge Here are some test text \hl{Some texts to emphasize}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Example to show why *TikZ* is not a good approach (wrapping).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{hl/.style={anchor=base,fill = lightgray,inner sep=3pt}}
\begin{document} 
{\Huge Here are some test text. \tikz[baseline]\node[hl]{Some texts to emphasize, but it won't wrap to a new line};}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it looks great

Comment: @hebtuzrl If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 0):

Add option `baseline=0` to your `tikz` command and `anchor=text` to your `node`:

```
text \tikz[baseline=0]{\node[anchor=text, inner sep=1ex, fill=yellow] {hilite};}
```

- the first options forces tikZ's x-axis to be aligned with the
  baseline of the surrounding tex
- the second option forces tikZ's x-axis to be used as baseline for the
  text inside your node

Full code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \begin{document} 
  Here are some test text{ \tikz[baseline=0] \draw (0,-1) node[anchor=text, draw,minimum width=1mm, minimum height=1mm, align=center,inner sep=0.5mm, outer sep=0mm,rectangle,fill = gray] {Some texts to emphasize}; }
   \end{document}
```